# скругление углов для изображения

Tags: css, css3

Сразу к делу,вот скриншот моей верстки: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

поместил изображение во внутрь блока углы которого скруглены,но те углы
где находится изображение(правый-верх,правый-низ) не скруглены.Изображения добавлено как фон

```css
.rightcol{
    width: 94%;
    background: url("img/main_bg.png") no-repeat center / cover;

}
```

если бы изображение было в html то применил бы скругление к нему.Как быть?

Answer (score 2):

Либо к блоку **в** котором находятся .rightcol **и** .leftcol добавить

```
overflow: hidden;
```

Либо в .rightcol добавить следующие свойства

```
border-top-right-radius: 20px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
```